# htaccess change period to dash after subfolder

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a tricky htaccess question if anyone can help…

I want to make it so that any periods ‘.’ are converted to dashes ‘-‘ for certain URLs (anything after a particular folder: www.mysite.com/folder).

So for example: www.mysite.com/hello.world will remain as www.mysite.com/hello.world
BUT www.mysite.com/folder/hello.world will become www.mysite.com/folder/hello-world.

Sometimes there may be more than one period. Eg: www.mysite.com/folder/hello.world.2 should become www.mysite.com/folder/hello-world-2

To add one more layer of complexity: I cant access /folder/ so I can’t put the .htaccess file in there, it needs to be done from the root .htaccess file.

I’ve been searching a lot and cant find much on how to do this. If anyone can help with this I would really grateful!

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place these 2 rules in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule "^(folder)/([^.]*)\.+([^.]*\..*)$" /$1/$2-$3 [L,NC]
RewriteRule "^(folder)/([^.]*)\.([^.]*)$" /$1/$2-$3 [L,NC,R=302]
```